# How to set the values of a new incident?

Tags: c#, servicemanager

I'm writing a C# code that creates a new Service Manager 2012 Incident and set its values I'm having a problem setting the "Source", "Classification Category", and "Affected User" values for the incident,, any help please?
thanks,,

Comment: i need a function to retrieve the data inside Incident Source list and Incident Classification Category list

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in these pages:

http://scsmnz.net/c-code-snippets-for-service-manager-1/

http://blog.scsmsolutions.com/2011/09/codesnipets-for-scsm-2010-sdk/

There is no difference between SCSM 2010 and 2012 incident creation.